# Why getElementsByTagName() return an empty collection?

Tags: 2010, javascript, custom-form, modal-dialog

I'm using javascript inside the console of Firefox and this method does not work as well as 'getElementsByClassName()'. I specifically added class attribute to my tags in order to access. Could someone help me?

I'm trying to use those methods to get tags inside a modal list new form.

Sharepoint 2010, Firefox 31.5.3

Comment: Use `document.getElementsByClassName` if you have added a class for selecting. I doubt the tag names are specific enough for you to be useful without further filtering.

Comment: I do use both of them without any results. getElementsByClassName('myclass'),  getElementsByClassName("myclass"), getElementsByTagName('select') all of them return an empty Htmlcollection. I can see my 'select' tag when looking at the dom as well as my class 'myclass'...

Comment: Try document.querySelectorAll("<class name here>")...then loop over the collection. See if that works.

Comment: Hang on, OP has mentioned a "modal list new form", this is rendered within in IFrame if I remember right - can someone check that getElementsBy... work from a parent frame into a child iframe?

Comment: Tank you James Love it was that. Obviously, I have to first get the IFrame and then access the children.